# jQuery Toggle - should close only on clicking the header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

The Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bscn3/

Scenario:
I want to use nested toggles inside tabbed containers, as in the fiddle.

My Issue:
When I click on Main Toggle ("Toggle 1") or ("Toggle 2"), the inner contents display.
But it closes if I click on anything inside. For Eg. If I click on Toggle 2, and if I click on Tab 1 -> Nested Toggle 1, Toggle 2 itself closes.

I want it to remain open.

My Guess:
The JQuery working closes the toggle if anything related to the Toggle (Even text content) is clicked.

My Need:
I want the Toggle to close only if those rectangular headers are clicked.

Also, if you can help clean up the code in such a way, that I don't need to write separate JS to make inner nested Toggles work independently of its parent or children toggles, it would great.

Currently I have two Toggle JS Functions written for the two toggles in example.

//TOGGLE

```
$('.toggle-view li').click(function () {
    var text = $(this).children('.t');

    if (text.is(':hidden')) {
        text.slideDown('fast');
        $(this).children('.toggle').addClass('tactive');      
    } else {
        text.slideUp('fast');
        $(this).children('.toggle').removeClass('tactive');       
    }       
});
```

//TOGGLE L2

```
$('.toggle-view2 li').click(function () {
    var text2 = $(this).children('.t2');

    if (text2.is(':hidden')) {
        text2.slideDown('fast');
        $(this).children('.toggle2').addClass('tactive2');      
    } else {
        text2.slideUp('fast');
        $(this).children('.toggle2').removeClass('tactive2');       
    }       
});
```

P.S. I haven't written the JS Code, I am using someone's template.

Thanks! :)

Comment: try not applying the toggle bind to the `li` element instead add it to  the `h6`, the reason its toggling is because when you click anywhere inside the li element it triggers the toggle event again.

Comment: True that! The answer with code is given by @Steven. 
Wow, I am starting to like working with jQuery!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a pretty simple solution...

It's happening because the toggle currently activates whenever you click anythin inside of the `li` element (which includes the other toggle elements: `.toggle2`).

The solution therefore is to make it only activate the toggle when the `.toggle`/`h6` element is clicked and change `$(this).children(...)` to `$(this).siblings(...)`

You can use the following as things are (same changes in `TOGGLE` and `TOGGLE L2`):

```
//TOGGLE
    $('.toggle-view li .toggle').click(function () { // Changed selector
        var text = $(this).siblings('.t'); // Changed to .siblings(...)

        if (text.is(':hidden')) {
            text.slideDown('fast');
            $(this).addClass('tactive'); // Removed .children(...)
        } else {
            text.slideUp('fast');
            $(this).removeClass('tactive'); // Removed .children(...)
        }       
    }); 
//TOGGLE L2
    $('.toggle-view2 li .toggle2').click(function () {
        var text2 = $(this).siblings('.t2');

        if (text2.is(':hidden')) {
            text2.slideDown('fast');
            $(this).addClass('tactive2');      
        } else {
            text2.slideUp('fast');
            $(this).removeClass('tactive2');       
        }       
    });
```

**OR**

Just use the first section...

```
//TOGGLE
    $('.toggle-view li .toggle').click(function () {
        var text = $(this).siblings('.t');

        if (text.is(':hidden')) {
            text.slideDown('fast');
            $(this).addClass('tactive');      
        } else {
            text.slideUp('fast');
            $(this).removeClass('tactive');       
        }       
    });
```

and rename all of the `.t2`, `.toggle2` etc. in your `html` to the same as the first one (i.e. `.t2` becomes `.t`)

Comment: That was actually my complete solution to the whole question!

Answer (score 1):

use `event.stopPropagation()`

i have updated jsfiddle

```
$('.toggle-view2 li').click(function (event) {
event.stopPropagation();
    var text2 = $(this).children('.t2');

    if (text2.is(':hidden')) {
        text2.slideDown('fast');
        $(this).children('.toggle2').addClass('tactive2');      
    } else {
        text2.slideUp('fast');
        $(this).children('.toggle2').removeClass('tactive2');       
    }       
});
```

Comment: A solution to the main issue being worked upon. Thanks for the same. But I really want it to not close on clicking anything inside the li element!

But I have come to know of this stopPropagation(); function from you, so many thanks for that!